# randomClick(box) in python / where l`m wrong?

Tags: python

```
import pyautogui as gui
import time
import keyboard
import numpy as np
import random
import win32api,win32con
from time import sleep


#def randomClick(box):And the 
#   x_click = int(random.uniform(box.left, box.left+box.width))
#    y_click = int(random.uniform(box.top, box.top+box.height))
#     return (x_click, y_click)

box = gui.locateOnScreen('file1.png')
gui.moveTo(randomClick(file1))
gui.click()

def randomClick(box):
    x_click = int(random.uniform(box.left, box.left + box.width))
    y_click = int(random.uniform(box.top, box.top + box.height))
    gui.moveTo(x_click, y_click, duration=random.uniform(0.1, 0.2))
    sleep(random.uniform(0.2, 0.3))
    gui.click()
    sleep(random.uniform(1, 2))
```

And the output :

NameError: name 'randomClick' is not defined
PS C:\Users\refor\OneDrive\Escritorio\Pyton>

l expecent understant why and go on

Comment: You need to define the function before you call it. Place the function definition _above_ the call and it should be able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

In python,you ***first*** need to define the function before using it.
Example code:

```
import pyautogui as gui
import time
import keyboard
import numpy as np
import random
import win32api,win32con
from time import sleep

def randomClick(box):
    x_click = int(random.uniform(box.left, box.left + box.width))
    y_click = int(random.uniform(box.top, box.top + box.height))
    gui.moveTo(x_click, y_click, duration=random.uniform(0.1, 0.2))
    sleep(random.uniform(0.2, 0.3))
    gui.click()
    sleep(random.uniform(1, 2))

# Continue your code here
```

Comment: I just want to make a click in a random area from a .png and this should be the code :

box = gui.locateOnScreen('file1.png')
gui.moveTo(randomClick(file1))
gui.click()